# Align vertically text in a multicolumn cell of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to recreate the last table on page 4 of [this document](http://www.cs.kun.nl/J.Hooman/DES/RealtimeLinuxBasics.pdf), and it should look something like this:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{20pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c }{Xenomai tasks} & \multicolumn{2}{ | c |}{Linux threads/processes} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c }{Xenomai services} & \multicolumn{2}{ | c |}{Linux services} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Real-time device driver} & Xenomai kernel & OS kernel & \multirow{2}{*}{Device driver}  \\
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)} & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{| c |}{Adeos interrupt pipeline} \\
\hline
Specific hardware processes & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{CPU + motherboard} & Specific hardware processes  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

As it is right now, only `multirow` cells are aligned vertically and horizontally in the middle. But for `multicolumns` such as the first one that has the text `Xenomai tasks` I cannot get the text to be centered vertically.

I tried different solutions from other posts, but I haven't been able to make it work.

For example, I tried the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{10em}|c|c|m{10em}|}
```

Is there a simple way to align the text in all cells to be in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table cells are not vertically centered because `\extrarowheight` seems to be added at the top of the rows. To compensate that, you can either use `\\[...pt]` instead ot `\\` or go for the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c }{Xenomai tasks} & \multicolumn{2}{ | c |}{Linux threads/processes} \\[5pt]
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c }{Xenomai services} & \multicolumn{2}{ | c |}{Linux services} \\[5pt]
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Real-time device driver} & Xenomai kernel & OS kernel & \multirow{3}{*}{Device driver}  \\[5pt]
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)} & \\[5pt]
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{| c |}{Adeos interrupt pipeline} \\[5pt]
\hline
Specific hardware processes & \multicolumn{2}{ c |}{CPU + motherboard} & Specific hardware processes  \\[5pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| Sc }{Xenomai tasks} & \multicolumn{2}{ | Sc |}{Linux threads/processes} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| Sc }{Xenomai services} & \multicolumn{2}{ | Sc |}{Linux services} \\
\hline
\multirow{3.5}{*}{Real-time device driver} & Xenomai kernel & OS kernel & \multirow{3.5}{*}{Device driver}  \\
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)} & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{| Sc |}{Adeos interrupt pipeline} \\
\hline
Specific hardware processes & \multicolumn{2}{ Sc |}{CPU + motherboard} & Specific hardware processes  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Please keep in mind that your table is too wide for the textwidth of a standard `article` document. In order to change that you might want to introduce linebreaks in the cells.

Comment: Thank you, this is a fantastic answer. And yes, you are right about the table width. I have changed this to fit the `article` document.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have full control per cell in a `calstable`, the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) is well suited for such type of tabulars. To centre text vertically in a cell, you just issue the commands `\vfil` inside the cell.

Here is an MWE for the tabular in question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals, caption, xcolor}

\let\nc=\nullcell                    % CALS Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent
\begin{document}

\small
\begin{calstable}[c]  % Left aligned CALS tabular

% Calculate the column width
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*13\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*2\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*18\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*18\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*2\relax} 
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*13\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/88*14\relax}
    }

% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 88

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0,4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}  % Rule between header and tabular body
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside vertical rules
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}              % Inside horizontal rules
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\green{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!80}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\lgreen{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\dgreen{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!80!black}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


\def\red{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{red!80}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\orange{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{orange!80}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\lorange{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{orange!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\yellow{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{yellow!80}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\plum{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{blue!30!red!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\violet{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{violet!80}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\brow
    \green\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Xenomai tasks}
    \lb\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Linux threads/processes}\lb\green
    \tb\rb\alignL\cell{\vfil user mode}\tb\rb
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \red\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Xenomai services}\red
    \orange\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Linux services}\orange
    \tb\rb\alignL\cell{\vfil kernel mode}\tb\rb
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \lgreen\nc{lrt}
    \lb\cell{}\lb\lgreen
    \yellow\alignC\cell{\vfil Xenomai kernel}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil OS kernel}\yellow
    \lgreen\rb\cell{}\rb
    \nc{lrt}\lgreen
    \tb\rb\nc{lrt}\tb\rb
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \lgreen\nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfil real-time\\devic\\driver}\lgreen
    \lorange\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)}\lorange
    \lgreen\nc{lrb}\alignR\sc{\vfil device driver}\lgreen
    \tb\rb\alignL\nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil software}\tb\rb
\erow
%R6B5
\brow
    \dgreen\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Adeos (interrupt pipeline)}\dgreen
    \tb\rb\alignL\cell{}\tb\rb
\erow
%R7B6
\brow
    \plum\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil specific hardware processes}\plum
    \violet\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil CPU + motherboard}\violet
    \plum\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil specific hardware processes}\plum
    \bb\tb\rb\alignL\cell{\vfil hardware}\tb\rb\bb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `calstable`. I will check it out